# Insert multiple lines from zsh history

Tags: command-line, zsh, history

I'm trying to easily insert multiple lines from my history into the current prompt (to implement https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/issues/1806).

Given I have the numbers of the lines, how do I insert a newline-separated list of history items into the prompt?

If I have a single number, I can do:

```bash
zle vi-fetch-history -n $num
```

But if I try to do that twice, e.g. with:

```bash
zle vi-fetch-history -n $num_1
zle vi-fetch-history -n $num_2
```

then the second invocation overrides the first one.

It looks like this widget [is implemented in C in the zsh source](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/3d7215cc8277b39cd1e24ce5a04376d45bfbabf0/Src/Zle/zle_hist.c#L1764-L1782), so I can't just extend it.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Implemented this using the accepted answer in https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/pull/2098

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With "numbers of the lines", I presume you mean the *history* numbers of the lines. In that case, you can use the [`fc` builtin](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-fc):

```
local -a histnums=() histlines=()
# Insert code that collects history numbers into $histnums
local num; for num in $histnums; do
  histlines+=( "$(fc -ln $num $num)" )
done
BUFFER="$(echo ${(F)histlines})"
```

Comment: That works great for single-line history items, but prints multi-line ones as `foo\nbar` rather than adding literal newlines (as `vi-fetch-history` does). Other than manually running sed is there an easier way to make this work?

Comment: If it were just `\n` chars I could just do `BUFFER=${BUFFER//\\n/$'\n'}` at the end, but I suspect I'd need to unescape `\\`, `\t`, and any other escape sequences to be correct here.

Comment: I now updated the code in my answer to fix this. Please try again.